# Python script has to work with temperatures

Tags: python, python-3.x, scripting

I have to make a script that takes a txt file witch contains all the months names and every day temperatures and export a file that has every month's hottest temperature and the coldest temperature of the whole year
im stuck in this code piece and i cannot get it to work my way, so i need help before i dismantle my pc... :) thanx in advice!

```
integers = open('temperatures.txt', 'r')

largestInt = 0 
smallestInt = 0

for line in integers:
    integers = line.split (' ')
    if largestInt <= int(line.strip()): 
        largestInt = int(line.strip()) 
    if smallestInt >= int(line.strip()): 
        smallestInt = int(line.strip()) 

integers.close()


print ("Smallest = ", smallestInt)
print ("Largest = ", largestInt)
```

---

```
january -16 -12 -15 -20 0 -1 -20 -2 -20 -14 -18 -8 2 -1 -14 -7 -15 -17 -6 -17 -17 -7 0 3 -20 -17 -15 -8 -12 3
february -9 -2 -7 1 -16 -19 -19 -11 -16 -15 -9 -2 -16 -4 -20 -5 -6 -17 -5 0 -16 2 0 -20 -16 -2 -18
march 2 -9 -1 -3 -6 -2 1 -2 -3 -9 -1 -4 0 -6 -7 1 0 2 -5 -10 2 -7 -3 2 -10 2 -9 -8 -5 -2
april -5 0 10 -9 0 -9 -8 6 -5 3 -1 4 9 -1 2 0 10 0 5 0 -10 0 6 3 -6 -2 -10 -8 -2
may 12 5 8 -1 -2 4 10 -1 7 15 7 3 6 4 10 9 13 6 14 10 14 2 6 12 15 2 14 11 9 1
june 12 5 17 6 10 14 9 7 15 23 29 11 16 18 9 25 14 8 16 22 19 22 23 18 16 16 26 24 22
july 15 8 21 28 18 13 9 9 8 6 8 12 12 29 28 20 6 9 12 8 14 18 14 13 23 6 24 24 17 20
august 7 6 5 19 18 18 17 20 15 11 7 10 13 12 20 11 10 14 18 14 24 6 17 16 6 17 5 13 11
september 21 19 21 9 13 18 6 6 20 7 25 13 8 9 14 16 19 10 7 25 7 17 16 15 17 18 15 9 19
october 2 2 1 5 -2 5 5 2 2 2 1 -2 1 -2 0 -2 5 4 0 1 -1 2 0 2 2 2 -1 1 4 -1
november -6 -7 -2 -7 -2 -4 0 -7 -8 -6 0 -9 -2 -3 -2 0 -8 -2 -5 -2 -5 -8 -10 0 -2 -9 -9 -7 -1
december -15 2 -11 -14 -15 -5 -5 -18 -18 -19 0 0 2 -7 -16 -7 -4 -1 -1 -16 -18 -10 -3 -19 -6 -16 -16 -8 -2 -18
```

Comment: `max(map(int,line.split(' ')[1:]))` `min(currentMin,*map(int,line.split(' ')[1:]))`

Comment: Sorry there are too many evident errors here: the `integers` files object is erased to contain a list (`integers = line.split (' ')`!) so it is lost after first line, largest and smallest should not be both initialized to 0 but smallest to a large value an largest to a small value. And use `with` to have a nice Pythonic block around the open file...

Answer (score 0):

There are many errors in your code. You mentioned you want every month's hottest/coldest temperatures, yet the intention of your code appears to be to find the smallest/largest temperatures over all lines (therefore the entire year).

I recommend using the `with` statement with the open function, it will automatically close the file for you.

`integers = line.split (' ')` will return a list of strings. Though be wary of `\n` characters at the end of each line. Also the first element of the list will be the month, so you need to separate this from the numbers.

`if largestInt <= int(line.strip())` is wrong. `line` is the entire line as a string, `strip()` simply removes whitespace from the start and end of the string. If you want to make this comparison, use the `max()` function on a list of integers. Alternatively iterate over the list and compare each element. Make sure to actually convert the numbers in the list returned from the `split()` function to integers before making a comparison such as this.

Regardless here is what you should be aiming for. I will let you figure out the rest.

```
with open('temperatures.txt', 'r') as integers:
    for line in integers:
        data = line.rstrip().split(' ')
        month, integers = data[0], [int(x) for x in data[1:]]
        print(month, min(integers), max(integers))
```